# How to recover corrupted Bitcoin-Core blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, synchronization, reindex

I recently experienced a I/O error resulting in data block corruption or index corruption cause bitcoin-qt wasn't quitting so I forced bitcoin core to shutdown without killin it properly. I checked the harddisk..
when I restarted Bitcoin-qt it asked me a question:

> Error opening block database. Do you want to rebuild the block
>   database now?

Answered **yes** but when Bitcoin core came up I realized that I was 4 years back to synchronize with the blockchain. So I immediately stopped it again to look for more information before proceeding for safety

I found the relevant command in bitcoin-core options to rebuild chain state:

```
bitcoin-qt -reindex
bitcoin-qt -reindex-chainstate
```

Edit : This useful answer from user Pieter Wuille here:
 [When should I use -reindex-chainstate and when -reindex](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/60711/11928) answers my second question.

> -reindex:

```
wipes the chainstate (the UTXO set)
wipes the block index (the database with information about which block is where on disk)
rebuilds the block index (by going over all blk*.dat files, and finding things in it that look like blocks)
rebuilds the chainstate (redoing all validation for blocks) based on the blocks now in the index
```

> -reindex-chainstate:

```
wipes the chainstate
rebuilds the chainstate using the blocks in the index you had before
```

Found this bitcoin.se answer [Bitcoind --reindex vs starting allover again](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63067/bitcoind-reindex-vs-starting-allover-again) but made me a bit uncertain on what to do next in order to retrieve my database **without** downloading the whole blockchain from the start

*What would be the proper and fastest possible ways to rebuild/recheck my blockchain from Bitcoin-qt?*

*What is the difference of use between of `bitcoin-qt -reindex` vs `bitcoin-qt -reindex-chainstate`?*

Answer (score 4):

From: [When should I use -reindex-chainstate and when -reindex](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60709/when-should-i-use-reindex-chainstate-and-when-reindex)

> **-reindex**:
>
> wipes the chainstate (the UTXO set) wipes the block index (the
> database with information about which block is where on disk) rebuilds
> the block index (by going over all blk*.dat files, and finding things
> in it that look like blocks) rebuilds the chainstate (redoing all
> validation for blocks) based on the blocks now in the index
>
> **-reindex-chainstate:**
>
> wipes the chainstate rebuilds the chainstate using the blocks in the
> index you had before The latter should be strictly faster, as it does
> not need to rebuild the block index first. Perhaps the progress bar
> during reindex confuses you: that progress is only for the rebuilding
> of the index. The recreation of the chainstate happens after that
> rebuild is completed.
>
> You should use **-reindex** only when you were running in pruning mode, or
> if you suspect the blocks on disk are actually corrupted. Otherwise,
> when you only suspect corruption of the chainstate (which is far more
> likely), use **-reindex-chainstate**.

With `-reindex` I was able to restore my corrupted data