# Downloading of Bitcoin Core node stopped at 65.5%

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, error

My downloading of Bitcoin Core node stopped at 65.5%. I'm new to coding, but checked debug.log anyways and got the following ream of error messages:

```
2023-10-06T01:58:47Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:58:47Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:58:47Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:52Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:52Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:52Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:52Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:53Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:53Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:53Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:53Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:55Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:55Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:55Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:55Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:56Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:56Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:56Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:56Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:57Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:58Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:58Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:58Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:58Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
2023-10-06T01:59:59Z ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed (Failed to read block)
2023-10-06T01:59:59Z ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at FlatFilePos(nFile=2274, nPos=8385995)
2023-10-06T01:59:59Z *** Failed to read block
2023-10-06T01:59:59Z Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
```

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like a hardware failure.

Comment: Maybe `blocks/blk02274.dat` is corrupted? Perhaps *[How to recover corrupted Bitcoin-Core blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/65680/13866)* is relevant?